# how to create new line after tag in xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I use xml serialization to create my xml snippets. each serialization does not create linebreak at the end resulting in open tags following close tags. See example output below where the close tag  is followed in same line open tag 
how can i force the serialization object to be in a new line?

```
    maxmumleewayinticks=Instrument.MasterInstrument.TickSize*2;

    string filename="c:\\temp\\Strategyxmlfile" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".xml";
    settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.IndentChars = "  ";
    settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";
    settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    settings.CloseOutput = false;   
    writer= new StreamWriter(filename);

    ns.Add("", "");
   // write and close the bar

   XmlSerializer serializer = new        XmlSerializer(typeof( DecisionBar));

   w =XmlWriter.Create(writer,settings);

   serializer.Serialize(w, decision,ns);
```

Output:

```
<DecisionBar EntryOrExit="ENTRY">
  <mfe>0.0001</mfe>
  <mae>-0.0002</mae>
  <bartime>2012-07-25T21:43:00</bartime>
  <frequency>1 MINUTES</frequency>
  <HH7>true</HH7>
  <crossover>true</crossover>
  <currentprofitability>0.0001</currentprofitability>
  <entryPointLong>1.032</entryPointLong>
  <entryPointShort>1.0308</entryPointShort>
  <exitStopFull>1.031</exitStopFull>
  <exitStopPartial>0</exitStopPartial>
 </DecisionBar><DecisionBar> 
  <mfe>0.0001</mfe>
  <mae>-0.0002</mae>
  <bartime>2012-07-25T21:44:00</bartime>
  <frequency>1 MINUTES</frequency>
  <HH7>false</HH7>
  <crossover>false</crossover>
  <currentprofitability>0.0001</currentprofitability>
  <entryPointLong>0</entryPointLong>
  <entryPointShort>0</entryPointShort>
  <exitStopFull>0</exitStopFull>
  <exitStopPartial>0</exitStopPartial>
</DecisionBar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0540__XML/SpecifyformatandindentationforobjectXMLserialization.htm):

```
try
{
    MemberList g = new MemberList("group name");
    g.members[0] = new Member("mem 1");
    g.members[1] = new Member("mem 2");
    g.members[2] = new Member("mem 3");

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    tw.Indentation = 4;

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MemberList));
    ser.Serialize(tw, g);

    tw.Close();
    sw.Close();

    Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

This will give you the desired results, although it requires some additional work, not just specifying some options on the XmlSerializer.

**Edit:** There are a bunch of variations.  I found this one [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=xmlserializer+formatting); you can do the same.